# DAX convert date

Tags: dax, ssas

I am using SSAS, and i have a model.bim, in order to bring data from my SQL SERVER DATABASE to the model SSAS.

in database i have table with 2 columns, **both column are of STRING TYPE**:

```
col1Source_DB | timedatecolonne      |
prd1          | 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z |
prd2          | 2022-12-10T00:00:00Z |
```

i want to bring data to the model SSAS but transform date to this format "YYYY-MM-DD"

I am using , this code in model.bim

```
{
'name' : 'table name in model', 
'description' : 'test table',
'Columns' : 
 [
   {'name' : 'col1',
    'datatype' : 'int64',
    'sourcecolumn' : 'col1Source_DB' 
   },
   {'name' : 'colDate',
    'datatype' : 'datetime',
    'sourcecolumn' : 'timedatecolonne',
    'formatString' : 'yyyy-MM-dd'  
   }
 ]
}
```

with this json i have mismatch type column on date , how to traansform the date to YYYY-MM-DD

i put formatString:yyyy-MM-dd
but not resolving the issue

i have done this as well, if you see

```
{
'name' : 'table name in model', 
'description' : 'test table',
'Columns' : 
 [
   {'name' : 'col1',
    'datatype' : 'int64',
    'sourcecolumn' : 'col1Source_DB' 
   },
   {'name' : 'colDate',
    'datatype' : 'string',
    'sourcecolumn' : 'timedatecolonne'  
   },
   {
    'type': 'calculated',
    'name' : 'neWcolDate',
    'datatype' : 'string',
    'expression' : "left(colDate, 10)"  
   }
 ]
}
```

but not working too

Comment: I think it should be `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: nope, doesnt resolve the problem

Comment: If the string was in this format `2023-01-01 00:00:00` then it would work. Unfortunately it cannot convert (recognize) this format `2022-12-10T00:00:00Z`. Suggest perhaps bring it in as a string and add a new calculated column with the expression: `"LEFT([Test], 10)"`, and then you can safely have this as a Date column.

Comment: how would you test it : evaluate calculate (left('table name in model'[colDate],10)), it gives error table cannot be deteermined, am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try: note the `[ ... ]` around the column in the expression

```json
{
 "name" : "table name in model", 
 "description" : "test table",
 "Columns" : 
 [
   {"name" : "col1",
    "datatype" : "int64",
    "sourcecolumn" : "col1Source_DB" 
   },
   {"name" : "colDate",
    "datatype" : "string",
    "sourcecolumn" : "timedatecolonne"  
   },
   {
    "type": "calculated",
    "name" : "neWcolDate",
    "datatype" : "dateTime",
    "expression" : "LEFT([colDate], 10)",
    "formatString" : "yyyy-MM-dd"   
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?